Is there a closed form for $\int _0 ^1 t^{a-1}(1+t)^{b-1}dt$?

$$B(a,b):=\int _0 ^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt$$

What happens If we change the negative  sign to positive  ?
$$F(a,b):=\int _0 ^1 t^{a-1}(1+t)^{b-1}dt$$
This question came to me while solving this limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2} \right)^n dx $$
If we let $t= x^n$ we can get a form of that $F$ which is so similar to the beta function.
Is there a closed form for this "almost beta function"? Or is it another known special function? I searched for a closed form for this or the name of this function if it is a different type of function, but I found nothing.
